# PHP Class dinamicly execute select query(MySQLI and PHP)

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have problem to execute dinamicly select query, 'Select' function do not work, could you help me with it?

Here is table korisnici:
korisnik_id
korisnik_ime
korisnik_lozinka
korisnik_grupa
korisnik_datum
korisnik_salt

here is DB.php class, on the end of class is Select function.

```
<?php
class DB{
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_stmt,$_query,$_error=false,$_results,$count=0;

    public function __construct() {
        try{

            $this-> _stmt = new mysqli(Config::get('mysql/host'),Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/password'),Config::get('mysql/db'));
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }

        } catch (Exception $ex) {

        }

    }

    public static function getInstance(){

        if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }


    public function Select($query, $paramString = ''){
        $stmt = $this->_stmt->prepare($query);
        if (func_num_args() > 2){
            $parameters = func_get_args();
            array_shift($parameters); // remove the query from the list
            // Array needs to be bound by reference
            foreach ($parameters as $key=>&$value) {
                $parameters[$key] = &$value;
            }
            call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $parameters);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        $this->result = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();
        print_r($this->result);

    }
}
?>
```

Here is index.php file:

```
<?php
require_once 'base/init.php';
DB::getInstance() -> Select('SELECT korisnik_id FROM korisnici WHERE korisnik_ime= ?', array('s','Alex'));
```

Comment: Singletons are bad enough but they're even worse when they have public constructors

Comment: `func_num_args() > 2` is `false` for `('query string', array('s', 'Alex'))`. That's only two parameters so you aren't doing any binding. Also, I don't understand what you're doing in that `foreach` loop; assigning the double-dereferenced value back to the same key?

Comment: See, this is what I don't get about these PHP database wrapper classes. You've taken a 4 line execution (prepare, bind, execute, get result) and turned it into a 14 line function that doesn't work. It's a lot of complexity for no gain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DB::Select()` expects the bind parameters to be separate arguments, not an array. So you should call it as:

```
DB::getInstance() -> Select('SELECT korisnik_id FROM korisnici WHERE korisnik_ime= ?', 's', 'Alex');
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I now return this: $this->results = $this->results -> fetch_object(); in my index.php file and inside that file echo korisnik_id like this echo $this->results->korisnik_id ?

Comment: You should add a method to your `DB` class that does that.

Comment: Could you show me how that method should look like also do you know why I can't bind more then one param something like this: DB::getInstance() -> Select('SELECT korisnik_id FROM korisnici WHERE korisnik_ime= ? AND korisnik_grupa= ?', 'si', 'Alex,1');

Comment: Each parameter should be a separate argument: `'si', 'Alex', 1`.

Comment: No, I'm not going to implement your class for you. This is straightforward programming. If you were able to write the class in your question, it shouldn't be so hard to write this new method.

Comment: I tried like this: DB::getInstance() -> Select('SELECT korisnik_id FROM korisnici WHERE korisnik_ime= ? AND korisnik_grupa= ?', 'si', 'Alex', '1'); and like this: DB::getInstance() -> Select('SELECT korisnik_id FROM korisnici WHERE korisnik_ime= ? AND korisnik_grupa= ?', 's', 'i', 'Alex', '1'); but don't work just if I leave one param...

Comment: `si` should be a single argument, not separate arguments. Just like when you call `mysqli_bind_param()` directly instead of through the class.

Comment: I'm starting to get the idea that you have no idea how any of this works. You just copied it from somewhere without understanding what it does.

Comment: I also with si as single argument but don't work... I think this line something mess: call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $parameters);

Comment: I know how it works but I am new to OOP way of programing so it's very difficult to write classes and methods and do everything I imagine....

Comment: Make an attempt to implement the new method. If you can't get it working, post a new question.

Comment: I wana do something like this with class, so in future I don;t need to write whole code again....$stmt = $db -> prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE username=? OR username=?");
$stmt -> bind_param('ss', $alex,$max);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> bind_result($name);
$stmt -> fetch();
echo $name;

Comment: So put that into a function, and make it a class method. It's not that difficult. OOP isn't that different from ordinary programming.

Comment: I still can't find way how to do it right, it's difficult for me...Here I submited new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422307/how-to-implement-the-new-method-php-and-mysqli If you know answer please help,,,