# Adapting a select method to accept more than one parameter

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I need to implement a method `select()` that can bind one or more parameters and another method which will return the result to index.php.

Desired code called from index.php:

```
echo $this->_results -> korisnik_id;
```

this is the database class which need to implement `select()`. the present `Select()` function accepts one parameter...

```
DB::getInstance() -> Select('SELECT korisnik_id FROM korisnici WHERE korisnik_ime= ?', 's', 'Alex');
```

...but not more:

```
DB::getInstance() -> Select('SELECT korisnik_id FROM korisnici WHERE korisnik_ime= ? AND korisnik_grupa= ?','si', 'Alex', '1');
```

the full class:

```
<?php
class DB{
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_stmt,$_query,$_error=false,$_results,$count=0;

    public function __construct() {
        try{

            $this-> _stmt = new mysqli(Config::get('mysql/host'),Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/password'),Config::get('mysql/db'));
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                    exit();
            }

        } catch (Exception $ex) {

        }

     }

     public static function getInstance(){

         if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
             self::$_instance = new DB();
         }
         return self::$_instance;
     }


     public function Select($query, $paramString = ''){
    $stmt = $this->_stmt->prepare($query);

    if (func_num_args() > 2){
        $parameters = func_get_args();

        array_shift($parameters); // remove the query from the list
        // Array needs to be bound by reference

        foreach ($parameters as $key=>&$value) {
            $parameters[$key] = &$value;

        }
       call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $parameters);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    $this->_results = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();

   $this->_results = $this->_results -> fetch_object();
    echo $this->_results -> korisnik_id;

}


}
?>
```

Comment: Would it be easier to have your 2nd argument to 'Select' as an array? This would avoid your call to func_get_args and I think would simplify your logic. In any case it might be easier to read. Also, it might be easier to split your 'Select' into two different functions, at least to start. This would make it easier to test your multiple select, while keeping your select with single param intact.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're pretty close.

How about something like this in the place of your current forach loop:

```
foreach ($parameters as $key=>&$value) {
            $this->_stmt->bindParam ($key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);

}
```